# Worker Role Run Method Called Twice

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

**How come the run method in the Windows Azure worker role is called twice, instead of once? Is there a way to slow down how often the worker role run method is called?**

I am running 1 web role using a Small VM and 1 worker role using a Extra Small VM.

I have a task that is supposed to run every 15 minutes. It appears to run twice, instead of once in a 1 second period. Here is my log:

Auto sync has been called on 10/30/2013 5:40:17 PM for xyz@google.com using Orders
Auto sync has been called on 10/30/2013 5:40:16 PM for xyz@google.com using Orders

Sometimes, the tasks run in a 10 or 15 second period:

Auto sync has been called on 10/31/2013 9:22:33 AM for xyz@google.com using Orders
Auto sync has been called on 10/31/2013 9:22:25 AM for xyz@google.com using Orders

I would like it to say this:

Auto sync has been called on 10/30/2013 5:40:17 PM for xyz@google.com using Orders
Auto sync has been called on 10/30/2013 5:55:16 PM for xyz@google.com using Orders

As a result of the task being called twice, orders are duplicated in the order management system.

Here is my code:

```
    public List<MyTask> GetAllTasks()
    {
        List<MyTask> jtList = new List<MyTask>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from my_task where Seconds < DATEDIFF(SECOND, LastStartUtc, GETDATE()) AND Enabled = @Enabled", con))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Enabled", "1"));
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MyTask jt = m_Mapper.Map(reader);
                    jtList.Add(jt);
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        return jtList;
    }



    public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
    {
    string conString = "xyz"
    IMyTaskProvider m_TaskProvider;

    public override void Run()
    {
        // This is a sample worker implementation. Replace with your logic.
        while (true)
        {
            ExecuteTasks();
            Thread.Sleep(600000);
            Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
        m_TaskProvider = JMATaskFactory.Get(conString);
        return base.OnStart();
    }


    void PerformTask(MyTask task)
    {
        //mark task as synced for now. The last start date is updated to now.
        m_TaskProvider.UpdateMyTask(task.Email);

        //Update some data
    }


    public string ExecuteTasks()
    {
        try
        {
            List<MyTask> tasks = m_TaskProvider.GetAllTasks();


            foreach (MyTask task in tasks)
            {
                PerformTask(task);
            }


            return "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //LOG ERROR

        }
    }
}
```

I am considering adding code to pull the task details again, checking if it has already synced:

```
        void PerformTask(MyTask task)
    {
        //check and see if the task has been run already. This should prevent the double syncing issue
        task = m_TaskProvider.GetMyTask(task.ID);
        if (DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(task.Seconds * -1) - task.LastStartUtc  > new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, int.Parse(task.Seconds.ToString())))
        {
            m_TaskProvider.UpdateMyTask(task.Email);
            ISqlSettingProvider settingProvider = SettingFactory.Get(conString, task.Email, task.ECommerceSystem, task.StoreUrl);
            JMAQBCommon jmaQBCommon = new JMAQBCommon(task.Email, settingProvider.GetSettings(), settingProvider, CloudCartConnectorLogProvider.Instance);
            jmaQBCommon.AutoSyncWithSystem(task.Email, task.StoreUserName, task.StorePassword, task.StoreUrl, task.ECommerceSystem, task.Name, null, ObjectConverter.IntegerConverter(task.Seconds));
        }
    }
```

Is this a good idea?

Comment: How many instances are you running?

Comment: 1 instance of the worker role using an extra small VM.

Comment: are you absolutely certain the same task does not appear twice in the result of GetAllTasks()?   Is TaskProvider using an Azure queue implementation under the covers?  On a another (minor) note, your sleep is set up for 10 not 15 minutes.

Comment: I have added my code for get all tasks and I don't believe it duplicates tasks. It appears my code for re-pulling the task (GetMyTask(task.ID) has caused this issue to stop.